# convert yaml file to ini file with python

Tags: python, yaml, ini

I have this script:

```
import yaml
import configparser


with open('./prd.yaml') as f:
    input_data = yaml.safe_load(f)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_dict(input_data)

with open('./prd.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

But when I run this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yaml-to-ini.py", line 9, in <module>
    config.read_dict(input_data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 747, in read_dict
    for key, value in keys.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Here is what the yaml file looks like.

```
---
foo: /bar
```

I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Can you add a short snippet of your yaml, just enough to produce this error?

Comment: @usr2564301 it happens with even the simplest yaml.  See my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make up a section like so:

```
config.read_dict({'foobar': input_data})
```

So this is my resulting ini file.

```
[foobar]
foo = /bar
```